# How to send my kafka consumer data to spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

Suppose my producer is producing some messages and **Kafka consumer** is consuming those messages. Now I want those messages to be sent to spark. How can I connect Kafka with spark using python and send those messages from Kafka to spark?

Comment: What specific issues are you running into? The Spark documentation covers both reading and writing to/from Kafka

Answer (score 1):

You need to Spark Structured Streaming + kafka integration (where you can get the kafka events as Streaming DataFrame)

You don't need a separate KafkaConsumer, here Spark is consuming directly from kafka topics.

**Refer this:**

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#reading-data-from-kafka